# How to make a closure optional with a default value

Tags: ios, swift

I have a bunch of functions that I would like to be able to specify a default closure if one is not provided.  I can't seem to figure out how to do it without some ugly code.

So for example, I would like the `perform` function to accept an optional parameter called `closure` that is executed when provided.  Otherwise it will default to executing `myClosure`.  How can I make this better so I don't have to repeat the function calls?

```
class MyClas {

    typealias closureType = ((number: Int) -> Int)?

    func myClosure (number: Int) -> Int {
        return number * 2
    }

    func perform(number: Int, closure: closureType = nil) -> Int {
        if closure == nil {
            return myClosure(number)
        } else {
            return closure!(number: number)
        }

    }
}
```

Ideally, I could do this!

```
class MyClass {

    typealias closureType = ((number: Int) -> Int)?

    func myClosure (number: Int) -> Int {
        return number * 2
    }

    func perform(number: Int, closure: closureType = myClosure) -> Int {
        return closure(number: number)

    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? It works for me in Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: Sorry @robmayoff I updated my question.  That code works, but in my real code it causes a ton of repetition.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you've made made `myClosure` a method (or member function), which means it doesn't have the signature you want (it's instead a curried function, of type `MyClass->Int->Int`).

Either pull it out of the class, or make it a static (or rather "class" in the case of a class) method:

```
class MyClass {

    typealias closureType = (number: Int) -> Int

    class func myClosure (number: Int) -> Int {
        return number * 2
    }

    func perform(number: Int, closure: closureType = MyClass.myClosure) -> Int {
        return closure(number: number)

    }
}
```

P.S. once you do this, it doesn't need to be optional any more

Just to show it compiling as a non-static method:

```
class MyClass {

    typealias closureType = MyClass -> (number: Int) -> Int

    func myClosure (number: Int) -> Int {
        return number * 2
    }

    func perform(number: Int, closure: closureType = myClosure) -> Int {
        return closure(self)(number: number)

    }
}

let c = MyClass()
println(c.perform(5))  // prints 10
```

Comment: So close!  This solution won't let me pass in a closure though.  It should be optional so that I can either use the myClosure or another e.g. println(object.perform(2, { return $0 }))

Comment: It will let you pass in a closure.  You don’t need an optional for the behaviour you’re describing – that’s already how defaults behave (i.e. if you supply a value, that’s used, if not, the default is used).  Bear in mind default arguments are named by default:  `c.perform(5, closure: { $0 + 1 })` works.  Or if you use trailing syntax, you don’t need the argument name: `c.perform(5) { $0 + 1 }`.  If you don’t want a named argument, declare perform as `func perform(number: Int, _ closure: closureType = MyClass.myClosure) -> Int`

Answer (score 1):

Closure is first-class citizen in *Swift*. So you can provide default value for it.

```
class MyClass {
    func perform(number: Int, closure: Int -> Int = { $0 * 2 }) -> Int {
        return closure(number)
    }
}
```

Comment: So close! How can I pass it in as a function name? I updated my questions to reflect.